# Css Transform Not Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typography

So I'm trying to do this typography transformation. I have the letter in all white. When I hover the mouse on top, the top half of the letter should flip down exposing a different color. The problem is that it's flipping down the wrong `div`.

`tback` is the lower part of letter A.
`tfront` is the upper part of letter A.

HTML code:

```
<div id="letter-container" class="letter-container">
    <h2><a href="#"> 
    <div class="twrap">

        <div class="tup">
            <div class="tback"><span>A</span></div>
            <div class="tfront"><span>A</span></div>

        </div>
        <div class="tbg"><span>A</span></div>
        <div class="tdown"><span>A</span></div>
    </div></a></h2>
</div>
```

HERE IS THE CSS:

```
.letter-container h2 .twrap{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    font-size: 120px;


    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #000;
}
.letter-container h2 .tbg{
    background: #121212;
    position: absolute;
    color: #f2c200;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -10;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.letter-container h2 .tdown{
    height: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #151515;
    color: white;

    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.letter-container h2 .tdown span,
.letter-container h2 .tup .tback span{
   display: block;
   margin-top:-60px;

}
.letter-container h2 .tup{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.letter-container h2 .tup .tfront{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

    background: #151515;


  }

/*Drop down part*/
.letter-container h2 .tup .tback{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

    background: #151515;

    color: #f2c200;

  }
.letter-container h2 .tup .tdown{
    background: red;
    color: red;

 }
.letter-container h2 .tup .tback{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); 
}
.letter-container h2 a .twrap:hover .tup {

    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);

}
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/g4zja/

Comment: On mouse hover you need to change the color of upper part with a flip animation, or something else..?

Comment: You see how the top part of the A flips down. Its because that one is .tfront, I need .tback to flip down. But I can't css to specify that, I've been flipping both, and for some reason, .tfront is the one that shows

Comment: @user3337821 Not certain what the desired effect is? Is the "A" meant to display as the full "A", with top portion one color, and bottom portion another color? Without forming a "diamond" shape? Thanks.

Comment: when the top flips down it should be yellow A. when it flips back up, it should be a white A. @guest271314

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly is the desired effect. Maybe this?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/g4zja/1/)

```
.letter-container h2 a .twrap:hover .tup {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```